# Shell output redirect to multiple pipes

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

In cmd.exe, a certain command produces output in the form:

```
Asd foo content 1
Qwe bar content 1
Asd foo content 2
Qwe bar content 2
...
```

I would like to format it to instead produce:

```
foo content 1, bar content 1
foo content 2, bar content 2
```

How do I do that?

My guess is that a combination of "&" (parallel command), "|" (pipe), "findstr" and another command to cut out the relevant parts of a line can be used.

Comment: As for cutting, if the value is in a variable it can be extracted like this: `%date:~10,4%`

Comment: try wtih tee implementations for windows:http://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php   or http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/  or   http://www.commandline.co.uk/mtee/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pipe the results of your command into sed for Windows, but that would require a download of a non-native utility. The [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project has a free version of sed.

Here is a native batch solution that doesn't require any download.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('yourCommand') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln2=!ln:*foo =foo !"
  if "!ln2!" neq "!ln!" (
    <nul set /p "=!ln2!"
  ) else (
    echo , !ln:*bar =bar !
  )
  endlocal
)
```

The above will discard lines that begin with a `;`, and will also discard empty lines. Both limitations can be solved with extra code if needed.

The toggling of delayed expansion within the loop is done to preserve any `!` character that might appear in the output. The result will be corrupted if the output contains `!` and delayed expansion is enabled when the FOR variable is expanded.